# Search inside a word document table

Tags: powershell

```
$SearchString = "Table Text"
$regex = [Regex]::Match($PgContent.Text, $SearchString) 
if($regex.Success)
{
    $finalName = $fileDoc.Name
    $Selection = $word.Selection
    $finalDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 1
    $path = $outputPath + "TableText_" + $i + "_" + $finalName
    $finalDoc.saveas([ref]$path)
    $finalDoc.close()
}
else
{
    'ignores the content
}
```

This part of the code is where I am looking for the search string after splitting the document into separate pages. If it finds the search string it saves that page if not it deletes it. The code works great for text that is not sinde the table within the Word document. Do I need to do something special in powershell to make it search for table text?

Comment: Hi, is there any way for you to share a sample word document to test your script (and try to help) ?

Comment: I could make a dummy document sure. How do I upload to here? But you are correct it is something to do with the tables. I added a few dummy plain tables to the end of my document and it searches them. However the format that the tables are currently in, it skips.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use a 3rd party file sharing service for that.

Comment: never mind your comment got me to looking at it closer and the term I was searching for had a parentheses in it, once I escaped the character, it started working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great : ). Please take a little of your time to read this : http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html. Happy _rubber duck debugging_.

Answer (score 0):

The rubber duck finally found the glitch : the search term was in fact incorrect (according to OP's comment).